# POSTGRES to_timestamp() assumes UTC string is in local time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have imported a table to my PostgreSQL database, called  `staging`. Time data is stored in this table as a text column `timestamp` of format: `2020-01-31T00:01:59Z`. I know this data is UTC, even though this information is not explicit in the text string. I would like to store this information in a timestamp with time zone column, but I cannot find a way to tell PostgreSQL this data is in UTC.

If I run a simple `to_timestamp()` data is assumed to be in my local time. For example, see this call:

```
    SELECT timestamp AS textoriginal, 
       to_timestamp(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') AS to_timestamp,
       to_timestamp(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS perceivedutc  
    FROM staging 
    LIMIT 5
```

```
|textoriginal        |to_timestamp            |perceivedutc            |
|--------------------|------------------------|------------------------|
|2015-12-11T11:00:43Z|Dec 11 2015 11:00:43 +01|Dec 11 2015 10:00:43    |
|2015-12-11T11:08:38Z|Dec 11 2015 11:08:38 +01|Dec 11 2015 10:08:38    |
|2015-12-11T11:12:19Z|Dec 11 2015 11:12:19 +01|Dec 11 2015 10:12:19    |
|2015-12-11T11:16:24Z|Dec 11 2015 11:16:24 +01|Dec 11 2015 10:16:24    |
|2015-12-11T11:20:30Z|Dec 11 2015 11:20:30 +01|Dec 11 2015 10:20:30    |
```

How can I declare to Postgresql that this string is in UTC?

Comment: "*I know this data is UTC, even though this information is not explicit in the text string*". It **is** explicit in the text string: that's what the `Z` at the end means.

Comment: Oh, living and learning. I thought Z was just an 'end of the line' representation

Comment: FYI, for reference, under *Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)* in [Wikipedia ISO-8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): *If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space ...*.  (Sorry I do not have access to the actual paid ISO Standard.) If you are going to do much with date/timestamp become familiar with ISO-8601.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input timestamp `2020-01-31T00:01:59Z` is in UTC timezone, so, you just have to create the respective column with `timestamptz` type. Postgres will store it accordingly. The query below will convert to timestamp with time zone

`SELECT timestamp::timestamptz AS perceivedutc FROM staging LIMIT 5`